# Detect fb_share javascript button click

Tags: javascript, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook javascript firing on a “share”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7944221/facebook-javascript-firing-on-a-share)

Is it possible to detect when the share button is clicked in the pop windows when using `fb_share` ?

I used the new SDK and got it working using the response but I cannot seem to get it working when using the simple share button.

Comment: Related: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7944221/facebook-javascript-firing-on-a-share

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it is possible to get the share button click event inside the popup.