# Facebook javascript firing on a "share"

Tags: javascript, facebook

I saw this link here:

[How to detect Facebook share success? with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506213/how-to-detect-facebook-share-success-with-javascript)

But how do I implement that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you need to have the Javascript SDK loaded in your page

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      oauth      : true, // enable OAuth 2.0
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });    

  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
   }(document));
</script>
```

Next you have a function that contains the FB.ui code for opening the share dialog. Within the FB.ui function you can see where the callback starts `function(response) {`, where 'response' contains some details that help you determine if the user did share the message.

In the callback we do an IF statement. If the user did post the message response.post_id exists and contains the id of the successfully posted message so then we can do whatever we want, in this example an alert pops up saying 'Post was published'

```
function share(){
  FB.ui(
    {
      method: 'feed',
      name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
      link: 'http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
      picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
      caption: 'Reference Documentation',
      description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface with users.',
      message: 'Facebook Dialogs are easy!'
    },

    function(response) {
      if (response && response.post_id) {

        // THE POST WAS PUBLISHED
        alert('Post was published.');

      } else {

        // THE POST WAS NOT PUBLISHED
        alert('Post was not published.');

      }
    }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) you have instructions how to init FB Javascript SDK, then use function from your's link.